# How to do multiple imports in React Lazy Load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a file called index.js where I export my components , How can I integrate this structur into lazy load?

the following usage ,causing code confusion.do you have any idea ?

```
const AComponent = React.lazy(() => import("components").then((module) => ({ default: module.AComponent })));
```

[image]

Comment: `React.lazy` expects a default export. What happens when you try the workaround in that code snippet you posted? Do you get any error messages? Does something go wrong?

Comment: it works flawlessly. do you have any better solution?

Comment: Nope. That's the correct work around. Like I said, `React.lazy` is designed for default exports. If you are using named exports, it's not going to be pretty.